# How do I give my javascript anonymous type, property names with incremented counters?

Tags: javascript, json, anonymous-types

So here is my scenario, I am "serializing" some json data with anonymous types in javascript to post back to an MVC controller. Maybe I am approaching this problem in the wrong way, but I have a list of objects or an array of objects that are in a nested object. Below is a sample of the data I am posting back.

```
var items = [];
var counter = 0;
$("#table > tbody > tr").each(function () {
    var ModelId = $(this).find("#models option:selected").val();
    var Attrib1 = $(this).find("#attrib1 option:selected").val();
    var Attrib2 = $(this).find("#attrib2 option:selected").val();
    var Price = $(this).find("#price").val();
    var Notes = $(this).find("#notes").val();
    var ModelName = "MyObjects[" + counter + "].ModelId";
    var Attrib1Name = "MyObjects[" + counter + "].Attrib1";
    var Attrib2Name = "MyObjects[" + counter + "].Attrib2";
    var PriceName = "MyObjects[" + counter + "].Price";
    var NotesName = "MyObjects[" + counter + "].Notes";
    var item = {
       ModelName: ModelId,
       Attrib1Name: Attrib1,
       Attrib2Name: Attrib2,
       PriceName: Price,
       NotesName: Notes
    }
    items.push(item);
    counter++;
});
```

Tried to do this in a couple different ways (laughs are accepted) :). But essentially I need that property name to be the value of the variable e.g `ModelName`.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Steven

Comment: Unrelated, but do you have duplicate ids in your DOM? ```$(this).find("#price").val();``` should only ever be one value.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann you might be right actually, I was thinking in a different context. Let me try that really quick.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann you were right lol. I don't know why I was making that so complicated. I forgot about it just being an array and was thinking of ASP.NET MVC's naming scheme that was accepted via a normal form POST vs. an ajax post. If you will put this as the answer I will accept it.

Comment: Why do you need the counter? You're building an array; does the index not imply the counter value?